# How should I implement, and what should I call, a common base class for Area and Point?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclass, base-class

So I want a `Point` and an `Area` classes similar to how C# has `Point` and `Size`. Here are simple implementations of the two classes:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)

    # Many other magic methods too!


class Area:
    def __init__(self, width=0, height=0):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Area(self.width + other.width, self.height + other.height)

    # Many other magic methods too!
```

As you can see, the two classes are exact duplicates, except one has `x, y` while the other has `width, height`.

What would be a good solution for implementing some kind of base class for these two?

Comment: @Lucian Probably because *"As you can see, the two classes are exact duplicates, except one has `x, y` while the other has `width, height`."* A base class gets rid of duplicate code in multiple classes. Not saying it's the best solution, but it is **a** solution.

Comment: They each require two parameters in their construction, but that doesn't necessarily make them related enough to justify a common parent class.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 They both have like 10 methods in common, which do the exact same thing... Only different name for two attributes...

Comment: This is true Markus, your answer is ok, but the code always should be very intuitive and easy to read, but that's another story

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Yes, this is what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using immutable objects, you could subclass `tuple` to craete a base class for all of the two dimensional stuff:

```
class _2dTuple(tuple):

     def __new__(cls, hor=0, ver=0):
         super().__new__(cls, (hor, ver))

     def __add__(self, other):
         return type(self)(self[0] + other[0], self[1] + other[1])
```

Now when you subclass your `_2dTuple`, you can just create `property` getters for your `x, y` and `width, height`:

```
class Point(_2dTuple):

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self[0]

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self[1]


class Area(_2dTuple):

    @property
    def width(self):
        return self[0]

    @property
    def height(self):
        return self[1]
```

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, but are points "two dimensional stuff"? They can exist in any dimensional structure, but they don't have a "size" per se. Also, your solution gives both objects a parent class, but it does so at the cost of propping up clear internal variables (e.g. `self.width`) with less-clear ones (e.g. `self[0]`). I suppose it would make sense if you extend this to n-dimensional objects, as we don't have names for dimensions beyond the standard three (length, width, height), but for 2D objects I think the regular naming conventions may be preferable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will still wait for more answers before accepting, if someone finds something better! :)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 You're right, it depends on how one defines "stuff", that was rather ambiguous wording from me. And obviously clear names like `width` and `height` are better than accessing the variables via index, but since we're in a class called `2dTuple` which subclasses tuple, I don' think accessing the attributes via indexes `0` and `1` is too complicated for one to understand, even if it's not beautiful when written down. OP's question revolves around not binding the values to names, because he wants different names for the attributes in different classes.

Comment: Note that this implementation will not stop ``Area() + Point()`` from happening. Which may or may not be what you want, but at least to me it does not make any sense.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Why should it be explicitly stopped? This is Python, it's your own fault if you're appending areas and points together. I can also append a tractor and an area together in Python just because they both happen to have `width` and `height` (if I were to implement `Area` normally instead of this tuple subclass). How much sense does that make?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Nevertheless, python *does* stop you from adding strings and numbers. It makes sense to do that if you can do that trivially. Here, you are opening a huge barndoor of weird additions. In fact, *anything* which has ``__getitem__`` implemented and does return a numeric value for ``foo[0]`` and ``foo[1]`` can be added to both Point and Area. I would argue that this is a surprise and may hide errors. Some safety by using sensible attribute names should be given. Even things like ``collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)`` would be able to be added.